# SharePoint 2010 Access Denied - Temporarily fixed by Check Permissions

Tags: 2010, permissions, forms-authentication

I am using Forms Based Authentication and security seems to be setup properly.  The problem I am getting is that every so often, my users report access denied issues on one of my site collections.

I'll log in as the user and can replicate the issue, then log back in as an administrator and simply run a check permissions for that user on any library in the site collection.  The check confirms that the user has access, and from that point, the user will no longer get the access denied message.  I'm not sure what happens, but seemingly a week or 2 later I'll get the same problem, easily corrected with the same check permissions routine.

Right now, I only have a handful of users right now but in the very near future I will be dealing with hundreds and soon on to thousand+, and cannot live with this manual fix as often as it is coming up.  Any explanation/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a shot in the dark, but are you by chance using Output Caching?  If so, you may need to [adjust the options in the cache profile](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/configure-page-output-cache-settings-HA010120686.aspx) so that it caches per-user.  I have seen situations like this where a user would hit a page and get an error exactly when the server was refreshing the cache and then that error page would then be shown to all users regardless of permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You also might be experiencing the 403 issue.  Many have had a similar issue where certain pages would be unavailable to a regular user but as soon as an admin hits the page, the user can then see it.

Take a look here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/0187d4ec-7c28-4a3e-aed9-eef1ba25f123/

The last post in the thread contains a fix that worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to turn off batch compilation, and the page then behaved as normal.